# Integral over a simmetrical interval for sine and cossine

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How can I prove that:

$$\int_{-L}^{L} \cos \left( \frac{n \pi x}{L} \right) \, dx = \int_{-L}^{L} \sin\left( \frac{n \pi x}{L} \right) \, dx, \,\,\, n \in \mathbb{N}, \,\,L \in \mathbb{R^*}$$

Comment: Welcome to the MSE! It would be nice to see what you have tried. If it helps, both integrals vanish.

Comment: I don't think you can, integral of the RHS is zero (odd function over symmetrical interval)

Comment: These integrals are elementary. You should try by yourself before resorting to this site.

Comment: Does your $\mathbb N$ contain $0$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fundamental period of   $\cos \left( \frac{n \pi x}{L} \right) ,\sin\left( \frac{n \pi x}{L} \right) $ is $\frac{2\pi}{ (\frac{n\pi}{L})}=\frac{2L}{n} \to $ 2L is their period. Integration of sine or cosine functions over any period equals to 0 $\to $ LHS=RHS.